# Почему отруби так называются?

Tags: этимология

Отруби - это остатки от молотьбы, полезная вещь, содержащая много витаминов. Но вот почему они, собственно, отруби? Явно от слова "отрубить", но при чем тут рубка, когда речь идет о зерне и молотьбе? От чего их отрубают и чем?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому, что это не остатки от молотьбы.  Это твердая часть зерна, а точнее ростки-почки, (Потому там и  жирнее и богаче...) получаются при   мукомольном производстве, а на жерновах разрушаются не до конца. Потом грохот, потом паз, называемый отрубом. Туда и сыпятся отруби.
Это технология на водяной мельнице.
А при молотьбе получается МЯКИНА.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько мне ведомо, то грохот это сито - решето, кое служит для очистки, собирая в себя отработку - суть отроби, от этого и отруби... не нужно так ръяно цыплятся за гласные фонемы, ибо они меняются, в зависимости от диалекта, а фонемы О и У - вообще взаимозаменяемы.

Comment: ну и где ваша отработка, как кроме машинного современного масла? Отроби, это вы откуда выискали - гоните пример. А вот отруб - слово такое интересное, канава, которой землю разделяли, распахал канаву - получил отруб, его еще можно и топорм в доске. Поскольку рубить - это работа с деревом.

Comment: Примеры?..вот пожалуйста..охлопья-остаточные хлопья,ощепы-остаточные отщепления,отребья,они же отруби-остаточный продукт переработки злаков.